# How to insert date with yyyymmddHH24miss to date datatype in oracle

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I am inserting in to one tabel called `testtable` where `APPLICATION_DATE` column i am inserting a date but  getting error as not a valid month.how to correct it.Here `APPLICATION_DATE` is oracle `date` datatype

```
insert into testtable(APPLICATION_DATE) VALUES(TO_DATE('20180118165335','mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

Comment: You specify format and do not follow it.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input value is `20180118165335` then the format mask should be like

```
insert into testtable(APPLICATION_DATE) VALUES(TO_DATE('20180118165335','yyyymmddhh24miss'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `.Net` tag on the question. If you're using .Net and worried about formatting a string value for use in SQL, *you're going about this very wrong.* It's not clear whether you're using ODP.Net or OracleClient, but either way what you want is to **first parse the value into a .Net DateTime object.** Assuming C#, but the VB.Net code isn't very different:

```
string input = "20180118165335";
DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Once you have the DateTime value, you build the SQL string like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(APPLICATION_DATE) VALUES ( :AppDate );";
```

Note how simple that string is. No conversions. No worrying about the format. *No concatenation.* Just a placeholder.

Then you use those two variables like this:

```
using (var cn = new OracleConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd  new OracleCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":AppDate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = output;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

An important feature of this sample is the `output` value is **never** substituted directly into the SQL command text, not even on the server. This prevents any possibility of SQL injection attacks. Additionally, using query parameters in this way ensures proper conversion to an Oracle `Date` value, without any need to worry about messy formats.

This also tends to perform better, because now the database server can cache the execution plan. We usually talk about this in reference to Sql Server, but Oracle needs to solve a similar problem, and I'd be surprised if it's not doing the same thing.

Comment: +1. Oracle is indeed doing the same thing. Another advantage of your approach is that if similar operations are needed to insert DATE values into different databases, the code is unchanged; it doesn't need to be modified to comply with each different database's specific conventions.